# Blender 2.8 snap, knife tool does not work properly

Tags: blender, knife, snapping

Have installed Ubuntu 18, Blender 2.82.7

1. Vertex extrusion to edge with snap enabled has gap (snap vertex to vertex is ok)

[image] 
[image]

2. Knife tool does not work with vertices on face

[image]
[image]

How i can solve it? I am using Blender for 3D-printing.

Best regards, Viktor.

**UPDATED**:
Have tried plane. Made 2 edges. Intersect with tinyCad. But plane was not cutted by 4 triangles, and still no snap in the center edge intersection point.

[image]

**UPDATED2**: J works for intersection.
But for vertices on edge/face it does not.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why did you use the haskell-snap-framework tag?

Comment: It is mistake. I wrote only snap. Have tried to edit, but always tag replaced with current. Removed it.

Answer (score 0):

The snapping issue is a limitation, just realized some time ago and found this:
https://developer.blender.org/T66422
Try using the built-in tinyCAD addon, it's very useful.

Comment: Thank you. 2 edges intercection works. But cutting poligon from face still does not.

Comment: That's strange, knife tool works for me. Without the snapping enabled, snaps on vertices, or with Ctrl on the middle of and edge.

Comment: Sorry posted picture Above.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but seems like those inner edges were created by "F" (Make New Edges/Faces). If you want to split the face, you should use "J" (vertex Connect Path). Now the vertex at the intersection is part of the face so Knife Tool works well.

Comment: Thanks. J works for intersection. Face splitted by 4 triangles now. But for vertex on edge not. Picture 5 above.